# How to execute a Model's function from a View in Backbone.js when a plugin event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the next code:

```
var Contents = Backbone.View.extend({       
    events: {
            "click #addAll": "addContent"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this); 
        this.model = new ContentCollection();
        this.model.on("add", this.contentAdded);
    },                  
    addContent: function(event) {
        this.model.add({ modelName: "all"});
        //Plugin event
        $('select').switchify().data('switch').bind('switch:slide', function(e,type){       
            //Do something

        });     
    },          
    contentAdded: function(content) {
        if (content.view == null) {
            var template_name;              
            switch(content.get("modelName")){   
                case 'all': template_name = 'home'; break;  
            }                                       
            content.view = new ContentView({
                              model: content, template: //template
                     });
            $(".box").empty(); 
            content.functionModel();    
            //render template                                               
            }       
        },              
});
```

When a button (`#addAll`) is clicked, a model is added to the Collection, then view is made, `functionModel` is called and template is rendered.
I want to execute `funtionModel()` when plugin event is done, but is neccesary  `content` of the particular model maked to call the function. And the plugin doesn't work in `contentAdded`.

Comment: Your explanation is a bit hard to follow. Can you try to describe the problem in more detail: what doesn't work?

Comment: When event (of the plugin) happens (`$('select').switchify().data('switch').bind('switch:slide', function(e,type){ });`) anything similar to this: `content.functionModel();` should be executed. Do you understand? Sorry for my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I've understood your problem correctly, but I gather you need to get a reference to the `Content` model in the `addContent` method. I hope this is correct.

Instead of allowing the `collection.add` method to create the model for you like you do now:

```
this.model.add({ modelName: "all"});
```

initialize the model separately:

```
var content = new ContentModel( modelName: "all" });
this.model.add(content);
```

When you have a local variable (`content`), it is also accessible in the scope of the plugin event handler callback. The following should work:

```
addContent: function(event) {
    var content = new ContentModel( modelName: "all" });
    this.model.add(content);
    $('select').switchify().data('switch').bind('switch:slide', function(e,type){       
        content.functionModel();
    });     
},
```